# Get network usage for each process (Windows)

Tags: windows, networking, process

So I've been searching for the past few hours for this and I can't get around this "issue".

Here's what I need to do:

I need to get a list of current processes and their network activity  (total MB Sent/Received since the application started). I **also** need to keep a record of what's been logged so far. So for instance, if I have a process named hello.exe with PID 2500, that currently downloaded 25MB and uploaded 300GB and said process gets closed, I'd like to keep it in the interface or at least save these data in a log file.

Originally I wanted to do it with PowerShell, but it seems like there's no easy way or anything out there that could point me in the right direction.

So, I checked other software like NetBalancer, Process Hacker and Process Explorer and they all don't keep an history. Process Hacker keeps the history of what process started and stopped, but nothing about the extra info I need. I'm able to set the Network received bytes and the Network send bytes, I just don't think any of these applications will keep the history.

The reason why I'd like the history is because I have a few scripts running at different time of the day and their process will eventually end and I'll never know how much data they actually transferred.

Are you aware of any 3rd party application that can help me out?

Thanks